# Swift handling wake from sleep and resuming play?

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an app on tvOS that plays streaming audio, using the `AVPlayerViewController`. This works fine, even when going the background. The issue is that when the AppleTV goes to sleep and the when wakes up the player is stuck and only a force exit of the application will allow me to start playing again.

Is there an event that my application should be handling to resume play properly? What should I be looking for in the documentation?

The essential code is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // loading details fron plist
    if let stationInfo = readStationSettings() {
        stationUrl = stationInfo["url"] as? String
        stationName = stationInfo["name"] as? String
        stationDescription = stationInfo["description"] as? String
        stationImage = stationInfo["image"] as? UIImage
    } else {
        trackTitle = "Unable to find station details"
        return
    }

    let videoURL = URL(string: stationUrl!)

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL!)

    self.player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)

    playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    self.player?.play()
}
```

Comment: Yes, please add some code.

Comment: @RomanPodymov I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an iOS iPhone App and I think the solution might help you. I am using the `AVPlayerViewController` to present a video in a pushed view controller. When the video is played in fullscreen and the App is sent to sleep then the video can never resume playing unless you exit the App. So this is actually the same issue you have.

Unfortunately, the solution involves calling a private function on the `AVPlayerViewController`, as there is no other way to get out of the fullscreen mode in any other way I know of. My AppDelegate holds an instance of the player view controller and when the App resigns active mode, the following code is called:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.getAppDelegate()
if let player = appDelegate.playerController.player {
    if let cl = NSClassFromString("AVFullScreenViewController") {
        for window in UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows {
            if let pvc = window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
                if pvc.isKindOfClass(cl) {
                    let dSel = NSSelectorFromString("exitFullScreenAnimated:completionHandler:")
                    if appDelegate.playerController.respondsToSelector(dSel) {
                        appDelegate.playerController.performSelector(dSel, withObject: false, withObject: nil)
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    player.pause()
    appDelegate.playerController.player = nil
    appDelegate.playerController.removeFromParentViewController()
    appDelegate.playerController.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
}
```

This code is working in Swift 2.3, so you might need to adopt it to other Swift or Objective C versions.
Please be aware, that this involves calling a private API call, which is a risky business.
Anyway, I hope this will help.

See also [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7866) on the Apple Developer Forum